# How to use VBA to remove conditional formatting when a workbook get closed

Tags: excel, vba

I understand I can use the code below to remove conditional formatting

```
Sheets("PCAM Commitments").Activate
Cells.Select
Cells.FormatConditions.Delete
```

But what should I add to make it happens automatically when the workbook get closed every time?

----------UPDATE------

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

Sheets("PCAM Commitments").Activate
Cells.Select
Cells.FormatConditions.Delete

End Sub
```

I tried this, but didn't work

Comment: [Workbook.BeforeClose event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.beforeclose).

Comment: @BigBen I edited my question based on the link you shared (plz see the new code), but somehow it didn't work

Comment: Where is this code located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should be located in the `ThisWorkbook` module:

Also there is no need to `Select/Activate` - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba):

Finally, I would use the sheet codename:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Sheet1.Cells.FormatConditions.Delete 'Change the sheet as needed.
End Sub
```